# Jquery input mask - how to prevent to enter invalid values

Tags: jquery, masking

I have a currency input field with jquery mask. I need to have min and max values and want user not able to enter invalid values. Here is my code:

```
$("#amount").inputmask("currency", {
    min: -999,
    max: 999,
    allowMinus: true
  });
```

But it works only on blur, when focus is moved away from the field. How to prevent to enter values not in the range?

Comment: this would be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359341/masked-input-for-currency-jquery

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya Thanks. I saw this link but I still could not find a solution anywhere for this specific issue.